# Return value is invalid memory address

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have some codes like this:

```
__block NSArray *array;
[manageContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    array = [manageContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];       
}];
return array;
```

Sometimes, the return value's memory address is invaild in release version.
So Why?

Comment: How and where do you verify that the address is invalid? Do you compile with ARC? What happens if you NSLog the array both inside and outside of the block?

Answer (score 0):

it'd be *really smart* if you examined what error is returned in the "`error:`" parameter of "`executeFetchRequest`", instead of expecting it to always be nil.

It may be that your fetch request is failing and the array returned is nil.

Also, if "`array`" is valid (i.e. there's no error returned by "`executeFetchRequest`", you should give the compiler a hint that these results need to stick around in memory instead of being released.  For example, set that returned array to a strong property.